# The answers for the question "Do you know any... near here?" (pronouns)

Tags: pronouns

How can I answer the question?

"I'm looking for a bookstore. Do you know one?"

1. Yes. It's by this building.
2. Yes. There is a bookstore near here.
3. Yes. It is near here.
4. Yes. The bookstore is near here.

Can I call the bookstore "it" when the questioner doesn't know it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the answers you proposed are grammatically correct and understandable. There are a few comments, though:

- Instead of "near here" it is better to use "nearby".
- "It" sounds (a little) as if there is a specific bookstore under discussion. Since the question is about "**a** bookstore" and not "the XYZ bookstore", replace "it" with "there is **one**".

So, the most idiomatic answer would be:

> "Yes, there is one nearby."

or:

> "Yes, there is one in this (that) building."

---

Even the question in the title should be written as:

> "Do you know any ... nearby?"

Additionally, you need to notice that the answer should not be:

> Yes, there is one nearby.

and it is better to use (e.g.):

> Yes, there is one over there.

In this way, you avoid the repetition of "nearby", you avoid sounding sarcastic, and you actually provide some useful information ("over there").

Comment: (1) and (3) are, of course, literal answers to the question "Do you know one?", but, as the answer says, not idiomatic in these circumstances.